# Opposite of RangeMap data structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm looking for a Java data structure `S<K extends Comparable<?>, V>` which allows the following operations:

- `put(K key, V value)` adds a value (for example *three items sold*) to a key (*on October the first*)
- `Collection<V> get(Range<K> range)` meaning *get me all the items sold between August and November*

I think I can misuse a `SortedMap<K, V>` but maybe you people know a better alternative.

An example instantiation would be `new MyDataStructure<Instant, Integer>` to describe the stock sold on various dates.

Comment: key value not clear, please put example, is key a `Date` and value a `number of items sold`, `TreeMap` could help maybe

Comment: I would pick a `TreeMap`.

Comment: I think the use of closures in Java 8 would help you to define such a method.

Comment: @ankur-singhal I updated my post

Comment: @kocko I thought so, too, since you can look at all elements of subtrees. Maybe that's why there's no equivalent in guava

Comment: I think you better customize a `class` with `TreeMap`.

Comment: @ooxi posted an answer, this would be more or less u want, might require little bit of tweaking at your end with keys/values etc

Comment: some treemap idea http://ideone.com/0cM2Wf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample answer what i understood, object inside `Map` can be tweaked.

1.) A scalable concurrent [ConcurrentNavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a `Comparator` provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

2.) `subMap`, `(K fromKey,boolean fromInclusive,K toKey,boolean toInclusive)`

SubMap will create a map based on given dates, whether to include them or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        ConcurrentSkipListMap<Date, Integer> myMap = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<Date, Integer>();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        Date myDate1 = cal.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date1 = "+myDate1);
        myMap.put(myDate1, 10);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, -4);
        Date myDate2 = cal1.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date2 = "+myDate2);
        myMap.put(myDate2, 5);

        Date myDate3 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Date 3 "+ myDate3);
        myMap.put(myDate3, 2);

        SortedMap<Date, Integer> outputMap = myMap.subMap(myDate1, true,myDate3, false);
        System.out.println("Output Map from "+myDate1 +" to "+myDate2 + "is = "+outputMap);

    }
```

**Output**

```
Date1 = Thu Oct 01 16:48:48 IST 2015
Date2 = Sun Oct 04 16:48:48 IST 2015
Date 3 Thu Oct 08 16:48:48 IST 2015
Output Map from Thu Oct 01 16:48:48 IST 2015 to Sun Oct 04 16:48:48 IST 2015is = {Thu Oct 01 16:48:48 IST 2015=10, Sun Oct 04 16:48:48 IST 2015=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

u may use nested map.

```
map<Object,map<object,object>>.
```

This Structure fit in ur situation as follows

```
map<monthnameobject,map<itemcode(or sequence),itemvalue>>
```